# JavaScript countdown popup

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a `div` containing a javascript timer popup after 2 seconds of inactivity, then disappear whenever there is activity again.

I think I am almost there, I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/e97z7nj1/2/) with some of my code.

The active, and inactive events work (i.e popup and hide) - I just don't know how to get the count down timer to appear within the `div`. Then ideally when the timer reaches 0 - the window will be redirected to google.com

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "timer";
div.style.display = "none";
div.style.width = "200px";
div.style.height = "200px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "80%";
div.style.left = "50%";
document.body.appendChild(div);

var timeoutID;
var idleTimeout = 5; 
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
    div.style.display = "block";
    div.innerHTML = "Inactivity detected. Redirecting in ..." + (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter) + " ...please touch screen to close this message";
    // show a count down here then redirect to google.com
}

function goActive() {
    div.style.display = "none";
    startTimer();
}
```

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/detecting_if_the_user_is_idle_or_inactive.htm) which has helped me with most of it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the countdown with redirection.

I have just added a setInterval function to be called every seconds in order to decrement your countdown or redirect the page. Also, this timer is cleared in the `resetTimer` function. The displayed number is updated using ID element using `document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML`

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "timer";
div.style.display = "none";
div.style.width = "200px";
div.style.height = "200px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "80%";
div.style.left = "50%";
document.body.appendChild(div);

var timeoutID;
var timerID;
var idleTimeout = 5; 
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    clearTimeout(timerID);    
    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;

    div.style.display = "block";
    div.innerHTML = "Inactivity detected. Redirecting in ...<span id='countdown'>" + (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter) + "</span> ...please touch screen to close this message";
    // show a count down here then redirect to google.com

    timerID = setInterval(function(){ 
        idleSecondsCounter++; 

        if(idleSecondsCounter >= 6) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);    
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";
        } else {            
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter);
        }
    }, 1000);    
}

function goActive() {
    div.style.display = "none";
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: @johnny_s I have just added a setInterval function to be called every seconds in order to decrement your countdown or redirect the page. Also, this timer is cleared in the `resetTimer` function. The displayed number is updated using ID element using `document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML`

Comment: @johnny_s I would say "why update a static text when you can only update the dynamic part?" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @johnny_s If your page has been redirected to Google, your are no longer viewing your page. So, the timer is no longer existing. Explain your problem with more details.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to fire a setInterval to update your div message till you need check out the snippet below.

PS: You need to add code to clearInterval when you are active in your goActive method, So next time it will start counting from 5 again and when your counter reaches 0 so that it doesn't go to -1.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "timer";
div.style.display = "none";
div.style.width = "200px";
div.style.height = "200px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "80%";
div.style.left = "50%";
document.body.appendChild(div);

var timeoutID;
var idleTimeout = 5; 
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
    div.style.display = "block";
    div.innerHTML = "Inactivity detected. Redirecting in ..." + (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter) + " ...please touch screen to close this message";
    // show a count down here then redirect to google.com
    idleSecondsTimer = setInterval(function(){
     idleSecondsCounter++;
        div.innerHTML = "Inactivity detected. Redirecting in ..." + (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter) + " ...please touch screen to close this message";
        if(idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter === 0){
            clearInterval(idleSecondsTimer);
         location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        }
    },1000);
}

function goActive() {
    div.style.display = "none";
    startTimer();
    if(idleSecondsTimer){
        idleSecondsCounter = 0;
        clearInterval(idleSecondsTimer);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @joyBlanks